# Put "Execute statement" result into variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to put "EXECUTE statement;" result into a variable so that I can get the result using simple SELECT command whenever I need it. The result will contain random number of column based on user inputs.
So, what I want is something like:

```
SET @RES := EXECUTE stmt;
```

and then I may apply-

```
SELECT @RES;
```

On a second thought, I want the result in-

```
WITH res_set1 AS (
   EXECUTE stmt;
)
SELECT * FROM res_set1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use variables inside your prepared statement.

You will have to structure your prepared statement so that it will give you one row at a time, for example:

```
SET @sql='SELECT col1, col2 FROM test WHERE id=3 INTO @v1, @v2';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
EXECUTE stmt;
```

After executing, you will have values from `col1` and `col2` in variables  `@v1` and `@v2`

To process multiple rows, use your prepared statement in a loop:

```
SET @sql='SELECT col1, col2 FROM test WHERE id=? INTO @v1, @v2';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 

SET @idx = 1;

REPEAT
   EXECUTE stmt USING @idx;
   SET @idx = @idx + 1;
UNTIL @idx > 6 END REPEAT;
```